# rotation of an object in opengl not happening

Tags: c, opengl, visual-studio-2008, rotation

I'm struggling with rotation of an object in opengl

It should rotate by 90 degrees on pressing the left arrow key.
but instead of rotating in that order, it is rotated randomly without any sequence.

also please check if redisplay function is used properly

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<glut.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>
int angle=0;


void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
                glVertex2i(100,50);
                glVertex2i(300,50);
                glVertex2i(300,150);
                glVertex2i(100,150);
                glEnd();
glRotatef(angle,0.0,0.0,1.0);
glutSwapBuffers();
glFlush();

}
void init()
{
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-400,400,-400,400,-1,1);

}


void Keys(int key,int x,int y){
if(key==GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
    {    angle+=90;
    if(angle>360)
        angle-=360;

    }

   glutPostRedisplay();
}


void main(int argc,char**argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(700,700);
    glutCreateWindow("tetris");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutSpecialFunc(Keys);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved

instead of `angle+=90;` use `angle=90`

Comment: In init you create a camera using glOtho. In display() you put a rotation on the camera, not the object. Proper rendering for rotating object would be glPushMatrix(); glRotatef(...); glBegin/End(); glPopMatrix();

Answer (score 0):

<s>glRotate must not be called between glBegin and glEnd. Speaking of glEnd: Your code lacks this (i.e. you're not properly closing the glBegin/glEnd block).</s>

You must apply the rotation to the transformation matrix before drawing stuff (not after): OpenGL is a drawing API. It just **draws** points, lines and triangles, one at a time. There's no scene and there are no models you could rotate after drawing them.

Comment: sir I didnt called glrotate between glBegin & glEnd.
There is a glEnd function before glRotate.
Moving glRotate before glBegin is also not solving the problem.

Comment: @user6145800: Sorry, I missed that due to indentation and reading this on a narrow screen.

Comment: @user6145800: See my answer edit. You must call glRotate before what shall be rotated is drawn.